# Get largest value from JSON object

Tags: php, json

I have a `$string` retrieved from cURL like this:

```
{"time":0.01,"total_rows":7,"rows":[{"id":968},{"id":969},{"id":970},{"id":971},{"id":972},{"id":973},{"id":974}]}
```

I would like to know  how to get the `id` that has the largest value (i.e 974), how can I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = '{"time":0.01,"total_rows":7,"rows":[{"id":968},{"id":969},{"id":970},{"id":971},{"id":972},{"id":973},{"id":974}]}';
$json = json_decode($result,true);
$max = max($json["rows"]);
echo $max["id"]; // "974"
```

Comment: Wrong parameter count for max

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? It runs fine for me here: http://ideone.com/9j3o8w